# approximate mean absolute deviation using histogram

Tags: probability, median

Given a sequence $A= a_1, a_2, \cdots,a_i, \cdots,a_n$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

We can calculate the MAD(mean absolute deviation) via $G(A) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n|a_i - \textbf{median}(A)|$, where $|.|$ is absolute value.

On the other hand, we can approximate the calculation of $G(A)$ using a $k$ bin histogram.

Compute a histogram of $A$ with $k$ bin and obtain $W=(w_1, \cdots, w_i, \cdots, w_k)$ and edges $E=(e_0, e_1, \cdots, e_k)$.

using $W, E$, we can compute an approximate version of $G(A)$, called $S(W, E)$.

I am wondering how can one bound the difference between $G(A)$ and  $S(W, E)$?

And apparently, $k$ is an important factor here. With $k > n$, <del>the two would be equvilant</del>, i probably shouldn't use the histogram approach

But normally we would choose $k<<n$, what would be the consequences?

As [Ian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83396/ian) pointed out, there are different ways to define $S(W, E)$, e.g.  1, the exact MAD of the distribution with PDF given by the histogram. Or  2, collapse each bin into its midpoint and use a discrete distribution instead.

My goal is to find an as accurate as possible approximation, so whichever strategy is accurate would be the ideal implementation. Meanwhile, I also want to have some error bound, so if whichever is easy to have an error bound is also appreciated.

Comment: How do you define $S(W,E)$? Is it the exact MAD of the distribution with PDF given by the histogram? Or maybe you collapse each bin into its midpoint and use a discrete distribution instead? (Neither of these will generally give the exact MAD even when $k \geq n$, by the way.)

Comment: yes, sorry I didn't have an explicit definition for them. but it is exactly as you said.  just haven't found a concise math formula for it aside from some pseudo-code.

Comment: Well which one is it? I think the two are not exactly equivalent. They are certainly similar though.

Comment: honestly, I haven't thought about the exact solution, but clearly, both would "approximate" maybe the first one? My goal is to be as accurate as possible. and for the $k \ge n$ case, the histogram would be the dataset itself. and I can easily compute the exact MAD.

Comment: When $k \geq n$ the histogram still has a width built into each bin, even though each bin only contains one point, so it still has residual error. Consider the trivial case of a single data point (for which the MAD is of course zero) to see this.

Comment: ah right... I guess in this case, I shouldn't use a histogram at all.  but let's stick with the original problem, if we were to use $k$ bins and $k<<n$, can we bound the error?

Comment: In the discrete version it comes down to controlling $|m_i-\tilde{m}| - |a_i-m|$ where $m_i$ is the midpoint of the bin where $a_i$ is located and $\tilde{m}$ is the approximate median (which might just be the median depending on your implementation). Except on the bin(s) containing $m$ and/or $\tilde{m}$, this will be $\pm (m_i-\tilde{m} - a_i + m)$ and thus be bounded by $|m_i-a_i|+|\tilde{m}-m|$. I think the two bins where this does not work don't change anything to leading order.

Comment: (Cont.)  Thus you should get a bound on the overall error that is proportional to the bin width, in the case of uniform bin widths.

Answer (score 1):

Say you define the approximate MAD by $\tilde{M}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n |m_{j(i)}-m|$ where

- $b_j$ is the midpoint of bin $j$
- $j(i)$ sends $i$ to the index of the bin where $a_i$ is located
- $m$ is (for simplicity) the exact median. Again for simplicity let us say $n$ is odd so $m=a_{(n+1)/2}$.

For simplicity let us also say that the median is one of the edges, say $m=e_{k^*}$. Then

Then

$$\tilde{M}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} -(m_{j(i)}-m) + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=(n+1)/2}^n (m_{j(i)}-m).$$

Meanwhile

$$M=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} -(a_i-m) + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=(n+1)/2}^n a_i-m.$$

It follows that the difference is

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{(n-1)/2} -m_{j(i)}+a_i + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=(n+1)/2}^{n} a_i-m_{j(i)}.$$

Thus in absolute value it is less than the average bin radius. This bound is not at all guaranteed to be tight, though.